# Meteor Up Setup "Start Mongo: Failed": Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, raspbian, mup

What I'm trying to do is push the default meteor app that is auto generated on

```
meteor create myApp
```

to a raspberryPi3B+ running raspbian stretch lite.

I'm stuck at step 2-3 on the Meteor Up page: http://meteor-up.com/getting-started.html

I must have something wrong when configuring my "*mup.js*" file in step 2 which is throwing an error in step 3 after running

```
sudo mup setup --verbose
```

I get the following out put in terminal:

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Docker
18.06.1-ce
Major 18
Minor 06
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Environment
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Environment
[192.168.1.30] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[192.168.1.30] - Copying mongodb.conf
[192.168.1.30] - Copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[192.168.1.30] - Start Mongo
3.4.1: Pulling from library/mongo
Digest: sha256:aff0c497cff4f116583b99b21775a8844a17bcf5c69f7f3f6028013bf0d6c00c
Status: Image is up to date for mongo:3.4.1
mongodb
Error response from daemon: Container 7d3155f5765a449501cb31f5150f4fb671a4e63b153fd49d702edb597679f1f8 is restarting, wait until the container is running
mongodb
Running mongo:3.4.1
9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb
Creating replica set
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
Failed connecting to mongo to create replica set
[192.168.1.30] x Start Mongo: FAILED

          ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
          Error response from daemon: Container 7d3155f5765a449501cb31f5150f4fb671a4e63b153fd49d702edb597679f1f8 is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
    Failed connecting to mongo to create replica set

          ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
          3.4.1: Pulling from library/mongo
    Digest: sha256:aff0c497cff4f116583b99b21775a8844a17bcf5c69f7f3f6028013bf0d6c00c
    Status: Image is up to date for mongo:3.4.1
    mongodb
    mongodb
    Running mongo:3.4.1
    9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb
    Creating replica set

          ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My "*mup.js*" config file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: '192.xxx.x.xx',
      username: 'pi',
      // pem: './path/to/pem'
      password: 'password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'ceresTestApp',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'http://app.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/meteor',
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/local',
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
    },


    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  },

  // (Optional)
  // Use the proxy to setup ssl or to route requests to the correct
  // app when there are several apps

  // proxy: {
  //   domains: 'mywebsite.com,www.mywebsite.com',

  //   ssl: {
  //     // Enable Let's Encrypt
  //     letsEncryptEmail: 'email@domain.com'
  //   }
  // }
};
```

I must admit that I don't know what put for the "ROOT_URL" or "MONGO_URL". The minimal config example found here: http://meteor-up.com/docs.html

Uses the same default entries for those two fields that I have kept from when the file was generated. So I'm not so sure that's the issue.

When I look at where the the error starts before looping in the terminal I see this:

```
Status: Image is up to date for mongo:3.4.1
mongodb
Error response from daemon: Container 7d3155f5765a449501cb31f5150f4fb671a4e63b153fd49d702edb597679f1f8 is restarting, wait until the container is running
mongodb
Running mongo:3.4.1
9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb
Creating replica set
Error response from daemon: Container 9c0755e4657323e0f4661713a32aeb0fa337debfab9d51c35437ef5879eef1eb is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

My interpretation is that MongoDB is both installed and up to date. That the problems begin when the setup process tries to run MongoDB with Docker because the point that keeps looping is referring to containers. Having never worked with docker before I don't really know where to begin.

**What seems to be going wrong with my MongoDB process when running**

```
sudo mup setup --verbose
```

**?**

Going to go watch some videos about docker while I leave this here for a bit.

Apologies for the length, I just wanted to provide as much detail as possible. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve the format of my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've recently discovered that under Meteor Support in the docs page of the meteor-up website that they state you must change the docker.image field depending on your version of meteor. Even after updating that, I'm getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for this:

1. Whit bild-in mongo change `MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/ADD_HERE_DB_NAME'`, set `oplog: true` and remove `version` where you have `mongo`. Like so:

> ```
> mongo: {
>     oplog: true,
>     port: 27017,
>     servers: {
>         one: {},
>     },
> }
> ```

2. Whit external database. Install mongodb on your raspberryPi3B+ or a different host. 
   Set `MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://DB_USERNAME:USER_PASSWORD@DB_HOST_IP:DB_PORT/DB_NAME'`
   Remove:

> ```
> mongo: {
>     version: '3.4.1',
>     servers: {
>         one: {},
>     },
> }
> ```

I recommend the second option because is easier to backup your db.